# Inform 7. Using 'Questions' by Michael Callaghan results in the game rejecting all input

Tags: inform7

So I'm trying to use 'Questions' by Michael Callaghan but for some reason I get a blank command prompt and everything I type into it receives the same response: "I didn't understand that sentence."

I've been following the manual and even went as far as to copy and paste massive chunks from his example.

```
Include questions by Michael Callaghan.

Getting to know you is a room.
The player is in Getting to know you.

Data is a kind of value. The data are complete, name and sex.

Gathering is a scene. Gathering begins when the location is Getting to know you.
Gathering ends when stage is complete.
Stage is data that varies.

When Gathering begins:
    now stage is sex.

Every turn during gathering:
    if stage is sex:
        now the current question is "Are you male or female?";
        now the current prompt is "> ";
        ask a closed question, in gender mode;
    if stage is name:
        now the current question is "What is your name?";
        now the current prompt is "> ";
        now punctuation removal is false;
        ask an open question, in text mode;


The player's name is an indexed text that varies.
The player's forename is an indexed text that varies.
The player's sex is a gender that varies.

Understand "male" or "boy" as masculine.
Understand "girl" or "female" as feminine.

A gender question rule (this is the gather gender rule):
    if gathering is happening and stage is sex:
        now the player's sex is the gender understood;
        now stage is name;
        exit.

A text question rule (this is the gather name rule):
    if gathering is happening and stage is name:
        now the player's name is the current answer;
        now the player's forename is word number 1 in the current answer;
        say "Thank you, [player's forename].";
        now stage is complete;
        now the player is on the bed;
        exit.
```

I have tried both 'questions' and 'Questions'.

Answer (score 0):

The Questions extension has a long example called 'Open Sesame' which covers all of what you'd like and more. It should be easy enough to adapt by cutting out what you don't need. The example can be viewed in the IDE, or here: http://inform7.com/extensions/Michael%20Callaghan/Questions/doc_26.html

Comment: I said in the question that I'd copied and pasted massive chunks from the example and what I meant by this is exactly what you suggested. I took Open Sesame and cut out the bits I didn't need. So, yeah, already tried that. The problem is that after I've finished coding it out and the game launches without error it immediately crashes due to a **runtime error** (where I7 is trying to do too much at once).

Comment: Much more people use the intfiction forum than stack overflow, so you might get a better answer there: http://www.intfiction.org/forum/